# In-place modification in piping chain

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm trying to modify some objects on the fly within a piping chain in `magrittr`. First try:

```
1:3 %>% (function(x) {x[1] <- 42; x})
#[1] 42  2  3
```

A shorter option using `l`:

```
1:3 %>% (l(x ~ {x[1] <- 42; x}))
#[1] 42  2  3
```

I'd like to know if the same is possible without the need of defining any lambda. What's the shortest way to do that? Can I use the assignment operator `<-` and placeholder `.` for that? Something similar to (note the readability)

```
1:3 %>% {.[1] <- 42} # invisible 42 instead
```

I understand that the last result is natural (the operator returns value invisibly). How can one bypass that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
> 1:3 %>% replace(1, 42)
[1] 42  2  3
```

Comment: Just another case of the golden "there is always a base function for that" rule; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The big idea with these pipes is to make things readable, and sticking function definitions inline undoes that to a certain extent. I'd rather define a function outside the pipe and use that:

```
> fidge=function(x,n,v){x[n]=v;x}
> 1:3 %>% fidge(1,42)
[1] 42  2  3
```

especially if you plan to do this in more than one place!

If you really do want to play code golf here, how about this:

```
> 1:3 %>% "[<-"(1,42)
[1] 42  2  3
```

Comment: I like the golfing approach, though it seems like an overkill. The first option seems to be appropriate, thanks.

Comment: In which case use `replace` and accept GG's answer!

Answer (score 1):

With e.g. `data.frame`s, the `within` function can be useful:

```
iris %>%
  within({
    Sepal.Length <- 10
    Width.Square <- Sepal.Width^2
  })
```

Although, one might also use `dplyr::mutate` for this particular task if efficiency and speed is a concern.

`within` works with lists too:

```
list(a = 1, b = 2) %>%
  within({
    a = 3
    d = 4
  })
```

@Spacedman: perhaps some aliases ala `extract` (which is for `[`) could be added for `[<-` to make your golfing example better :)

EDIT: in v1.5 aliases `inset` and `inset2` have been added for `[<-` and `[[<-` respectively.